# Storing HTML codes (like &#216;) as letters

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I need to read some test data from an html document. The problem is there are some non-English characters there shown as HTML codes (e.g. Ø - `&#216;`). How can I change those into a single character? Later I'll need to compare these characters to what user enters in a web form.

I'm trying to do this in Ruby 1.9.2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was on SO many times. But I can't find it. So, as I can remember:

```
require 'CGI'
some_string = '&#216;&amp;&gt;'
p CGI.unescapeHTML(some_string).gsub(/&#(\d+);/){[$1.to_i].pack 'U'}

=> "\u00D8&>"
```

`\u00D8` is your symbol. `&amp;&gt;` are just for example of use `CGI::unescapeHTML`.